# Can I steal another player's custom vehicle?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If a player steals a vehicle, customises it and saves it in their garage, is it possible for me to steal it out on the street and save it to my garage?

I am playing on the PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to steal another player's personal (insured) vehicle and save it to your garage.

It's only possible to take another player's vehicle if this player has set it to allow everyone to enter his vehicle in the interaction menu, but you wouldn't be able to save it to your garage.

You can steal and save another player's vehicle if it's not insured, as that means it's not owned by anyone.

Comment: I killed someone and stole their vehicle yesterday and saved to my garage, so I guess they had just stolen it as well.

Comment: If they haven't insured the car (bought cars are automatically insured) then they don't *own* the car, so yeah, you can steal those cars as they are owned by no one (except the poor NPC that it was stolen from).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to steal it when it is out at the street. However, you cannot bring it into your garage. This is probably to prevent griefing. If someone steals your personal vehicle, you can set access to only yourself in the interactive menu.